# Overflow and scrolling not working properly on HTML page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

I was working on [this website](http://www.entunc.nl) when I encountered a problem. It seems that if that when you scroll on the white sidebar on the left, the whole page is scrolls somewhat.

How can I stop this? I think the problem has something to with overflow, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: are you sure it seems fine to me, which browser you using?

Comment: on Chrome all works fine. Like @DanielCasserly say, which browser You use?

Comment: @user1697335 Upvote or accept an answer if it showed effort and if it was useful respectively...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wpstats image on the footer which cause that scrolling.

Add the following to your css

```
#wpstats {
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The width of your webpage is hard-coded and in this case is more than the browser width. You can add this to your CSS files:

```
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

which will basically just hide anything that goes out of the screen.

SO really needs to get CSS highlighting...

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, you'll see that except for a approximately 5px section in the bottom, the rest of the page is fluid, i.e., resizes dynamically as the browser windows resizes.

This annoying space is getting caused by an ill-placed image. The exact code responsible is:

```
<img id="wpstats" src="..." alt="">
```

To fix this, just add this code to your CSS files:

```
#wpstats {
  display: none;
}
```

Or add it inline as so:

```
<img id="wpstats" src="..." alt="" style="display:none;" />
```